# Partial derivative for linear approx question

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I present definitions and the questions follow.  I'm trying to understand how partial derivatives are used for linear approximation of a function at a point $(a, b)$ for a differentiable function $f(x,y)$ with real values from a point $(a, b)$.

$f(x,y) \approx f(a,b) + \frac {\partial f}{\partial x} (a,b) (x - a) + \frac {\partial f}{\partial y} (a,b) (y - b)$

and where $v = (x - a, y - b)$ at point $p = (a, b)$,

$f(x,y) \approx f(p) + df_p(v^T) = f(p) + \nabla f(p) \cdot v = f(p) + \nabla_v f(p)$

For example, $f(x, y) = x + y$ and $p = (0,0)$ and $v = (1,1)$

$\nabla f(p) = \begin{bmatrix} \frac {\partial f}{\partial x}(p) \\ \frac {\partial f}{\partial y}(p) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$, $\nabla f(p) \cdot v = 2$, which is as expected because $f(1,1) = 1 + 1 = 2$.

[image: a]
[image: b]
**Questions**

1. I'm confused how adding the partial derivatives results in $f(1,1) = 2$. The pictured graph for each variable $\frac {\partial f} {\partial x}(0,0)$ and $\frac {\partial f} {\partial y}(0,0)$ the value is $1$ in each direction.  The value at $(0,1) = 1$ and $(1,0) = 1$.  From what I observe, the two PDs establish slope of $\vec{x} = ((0,0), (1,0))$ and $\vec{y} = ((0,0), (0,1))$ but I fail to see how these two slopes are combine for the value of $f(1,1)$.  Is there a theorem or some geometry that establishes this?

Comment: This is the whole point of differentiability (just having partial derivatives isn't enough). You get a linear approximation result by superposition of the independent changes in the independent variables. It really is a theorem. (For *small* changes you can think about going from $(x,y)$ to $(x+\Delta x,y+\Delta y)$ by two steps, going first to $(x+\Delta x,y)$ and then to $(x+\Delta x,y+\Delta y)$, but, as I said, ultimately a proof — and some understanding of what "differentiable" really means — is required.)

Comment: I'm visualizing $\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)$ and  $\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)$ as two slopes $m = 1$.  I understand the slopes are for each $x$ and $y$ direction, therefore $f(0,1) = 1$ and $f(1,0) = 1$.  From the origin this is the surface raised at each coordinate.  I am having trouble understanding how to two PD components add together to arrive at $f(1,1)$.

Comment: Your $f(0,1)=1$ and $f(1,0)=1$ is of course incorrect. It's an approximation. The way to understand it intuitively is precisely what I said. You do two steps. Having the same partial derivative values is sort of confusing here. And you need to use continuity of the partial derivative (or something like it) to say that $\partial f/\partial y(1,0)$ isn't much different from $\partial f/\partial y(0,0)$. So *small* changes, not big changes.

Comment: In regards to you "two steps", first the $x$ direction and then $y$ direction this makes sense in terms of vector addition of adding the PDs at a point the approximation.  It seems like taking a step in the $x$ direction using a PD for $(0,0)$, then taking a step in the $y$ direction using a PD for $(1, 0)$ would be more accurate.

Comment: You're right, of course. But if the steps are small and the partial derivatives are continuous, the approximation should be pretty good.